# How to load an Initial View Controller from Custom View controller class

Tags: ios, initialization, storyboard, derived-class

In my `storyboard` I have a `FirstViewController` which is also an `Initial View Controller`. I have another `UIViewController` in my `StoryBoard` named as `BaseViewController`. I have added a `NavigationBar` on this. I want to derive `FirstViewController` from `BaseViewController` so for that I have written following code.

```
class FirstViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

But when I am running the App, it is not displaying the content of `BaseViewController`. Instead, it is loading only the content of `FirstViewController`. I want that every `UIViewControllere` which would be derived from `BaseViewController` should have its `NavigationBar`.What I need 
to change to get this?

Answer (score 0):

if the purpose of your BaseViewController is just to provide NavigationBar to ViewControllers. You can embed your FirstViewController(rootcontroller of NavController) in a NavigationController(set as Initial View Controller).
If you want different navbar for different controllers you have to set it programmatically like i do.

Take a look here-

```
extension UIViewController {

    func setNavBar(title : String, modType : ModuleType = .home, barHexColor : String? = nil, isBackBtn : Bool, isMenuBtn : Bool, isJummperBtn : Bool, isScreenshotBtn : Bool) {

        k_ModuleType = modType
        var barColor = "E14145"
        var arrLeftItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        var arrRightItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()

        if let aBarColor = barHexColor {
            barColor = aBarColor
        }

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: barColor)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

        if isBackBtn {
            let btnBack = UIButton(type: .custom)
            btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named: "Back2"), for: .normal)
            btnBack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
            btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.barBackAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            let itemBack = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnBack)
            arrLeftItems.append(itemBack)
        }

        if isMenuBtn {
            let btnMenu = UIButton(type: .custom)
            btnMenu.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu2"), for: .normal)
            btnMenu.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
            btnMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.barMenuAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            let itemMenu = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnMenu)
            arrLeftItems.append(itemMenu)
        }

        if isScreenshotBtn {
            let btnScreenshot = UIButton(type: .custom)
            btnScreenshot.setImage(UIImage(named: "screenshot2"), for: .normal)
            btnScreenshot.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
            btnScreenshot.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.barScreenshotAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            let itemScreenshot = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnScreenshot)
            arrRightItems.append(itemScreenshot)
        }

        if isJummperBtn {
            let btnJumpper = UIButton(type: .custom)
            btnJumpper.setImage(UIImage(named: "jumpper2"), for: .normal)
            btnJumpper.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
            btnJumpper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.barJumpperAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            let itemJumpper = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnJumpper)
            arrRightItems.append(itemJumpper)
        }

        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems(arrLeftItems, animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(arrRightItems, animated: true)

        let lblNavTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                                width: DeviceType.isIPad() ? 200 : 110,
                                                height: 40))
        lblNavTitle.textAlignment  = .center
        lblNavTitle.numberOfLines = 0
        lblNavTitle.textColor = UIColor.white
        lblNavTitle.text = title
        lblNavTitle.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: DeviceType.isIPad() ? 21 : 16,
                                             weight: .medium)
        lblNavTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationItem.titleView = lblNavTitle

        self.navigationItem.titleView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapTitle(_:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.navigationItem.titleView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
```

Then in FirstViewController's Viewdidload() method

```
override func viewdidload()
{
   super.viewdidload()


        self.setNavBar(title            : aTitle,
                       barHexColor      : nil,
                       isBackBtn        : false,
                       isMenuBtn        : true,
                       isJummperBtn     : true,
                       isScreenshotBtn  : true)
}
```

Comment: No, the problem is not the navigationbar but how to derive intial view controller from custom View Controller. Base class can have anything apart from Navigation Bar. In my question, the issue is not the Navigation bar but the deriving Initial View Controller from Custom View Controller.

Comment: Then in that case customViewController should be defined programmatically.

Comment: It is already defined programmatically. And it is linked to the BaseViewController in Storyboard as well.

Comment: In one objective c  project i had a commonViewController which was used as a base class for all viewcontrollers. In that baseClass i was programmatically creating a view which was used as a navBar for all controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface CommonViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>//,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{

    APIFactory *fireAPI;
    Supportive *support;
    MBProgressHUD *HUD;

    BOOL blinkStatus;
}

@end

@implementation CommonViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];



    fireAPI = [[APIFactory alloc] init];
    support = [[Supportive alloc] init];
    self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"IntelliDealer.sqlite"];
    self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.strVC=@"OrderViewController";
    [self setNavigationBar];


    if (self.epcCartOrder.count==0) {
        lblBadge.hidden = YES;
        badgeImgView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else{
        lblBadge.hidden = NO;
        badgeImgView.hidden = NO;
    }



}

-(void)setNavigationBar{

    NSString *query1;

    query1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Dealer_Spare_Order WHERE spareOrderListId=%d ORDER BY spareAddTime DESC",[[[UICKeyChainStore keyChainStore] stringForKey:@"DealerEnableOrderList"] intValue]];

    self.epcCartOrder = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query1]];


    [Supportive ShowLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"no of rows => %lu",(unsigned long)self.epcCartOrder.count]];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    CustomTitleView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, iPhoneX ? 100:70)];
    CustomTitleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231/255.f green:66/255.f blue:57/255.f alpha:1.0f];

    backButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didclickOnBackButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backButtonImage = [UIImageView new];

    menuButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    menuButton.tag = 100;
    [menuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didclickOnMenuButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    lblDealerName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lblDealerName.numberOfLines=3;
    lblDealerName.text= [[UICKeyChainStore keyChainStore] stringForKey:@"DealerName"];
    lblDealerName.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
     lblDealerName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblDealerName.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    lblDealerName.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

    btnDealerName =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnDealerName addTarget:self action:@selector(didclickOnDealerName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnDealerName addSubview:lblDealerName];




    addToCartButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [addToCartButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didclickOnAddToCartButtonButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    addToCartButtonImage = [UIImageView new];


    [self.view addSubview:CustomTitleView];

    [CustomTitleView addSubview:backButtonImage];
    [CustomTitleView addSubview:backButton];
    [CustomTitleView addSubview:menuButton];
    [CustomTitleView addSubview:btnDealerName];
    //[CustomTitleView addSubview:cartButton];
    [CustomTitleView addSubview:addToCartButtonImage];
    [CustomTitleView addSubview:addToCartButton];

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM () == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {


        [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 8, 45, 60)];
//        [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [backButtonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 18, 40, 40)];
        [backButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow"]];

        [menuButton setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 18, 40, 40)];
        [menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadnavigatio"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [btnDealerName setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 24, 590, 30)];

        [lblDealerName setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 590, 30)];
        [lblDealerName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

        lblDealerName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:22];

       [addToCartButton setFrame:CGRectMake(690, 10, 70, 60)];

        [addToCartButtonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(700, 23, 40, 38)];
        [addToCartButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadaddtocart"]];

        badgeImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];


        //badgeImgView.hidden =YES;

        badgeImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"order_bg"];
        lblBadge = [[UILabel alloc] init];


        if (self.epcCartOrder.count<10) {

            badgeImgView.frame =CGRectMake(36,9, 23, 23);
            lblBadge.frame = CGRectMake(7, 0, 23, 23);

        }
        else{
            badgeImgView.frame =CGRectMake(38,9, 25, 25);
            lblBadge.frame = CGRectMake(4, 0, 25, 25);
        }



        /*important--------- */
        lblBadge.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblBadge.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];

        lblBadge.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lblBadge.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        lblBadge.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        //lblBadge.hidden = YES;
        lblBadge.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.epcCartOrder.count];


        //[CustomTitleView addSubview:_textFieldSearch];
        [addToCartButtonImage addSubview: badgeImgView];
        [badgeImgView addSubview:lblBadge];
        [addToCartButton addSubview: badgeImgView];



    }
    else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM () == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){


       double customViewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - 40;

        [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5, iPhoneX ? 20:10, 40, 60)];
//        [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [backButtonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(10, iPhoneX ? 55:25, 35, 35)];
        [backButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow"]];


        [menuButton setFrame:CGRectMake(50, iPhoneX ? 55:25, 35, 35)];
        [menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadnavigatio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [btnDealerName setFrame:CGRectMake(90, iPhoneX ? 50:20, 180, 51)];
        [lblDealerName setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 51)];
         lblDealerName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];


        [addToCartButton setFrame:CGRectMake(customViewWidth - 8, iPhoneX ? 55:15, 50, 55)];

        [addToCartButtonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(customViewWidth , iPhoneX ? 60:30, 30, 30)];
        [addToCartButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadaddtocart"]];

        badgeImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

        badgeImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"order_bg"];

        lblBadge = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        lblBadge.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblBadge.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];

        lblBadge.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lblBadge.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        lblBadge.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        lblBadge.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.epcCartOrder.count];

        [addToCartButtonImage addSubview: badgeImgView];
        [badgeImgView addSubview:lblBadge];
        [addToCartButton addSubview: badgeImgView];

        if (self.epcCartOrder.count<10) {

            badgeImgView.frame=CGRectMake(28, iPhoneX ?  1:9, 20, 20);
            lblBadge.frame = CGRectMake(6, 0, 20, 20);

        }
        else{

            badgeImgView.frame=CGRectMake(28, 6, 22, 22);
            lblBadge.frame = CGRectMake(2, 0, 22, 22);
        }
        //lblBadge.center = badgeImgView.center;

        /*important--------- */



       // [CustomTitleView addSubview:_textFieldSearch];


    }

}
```